# How to autosave of images received on gmail to google drive

Tags: email, google-drive-api, gmail, ip-camera

I don't know if there's a solution to this, but let's ask!

I just set up a dlink ip camera. Every time it detects motion, it will send an email (from an address that I own, on Gmail) to my personal email address (on Gmail too). This email has six images attached: three frames taken before and three taken after motion detection.

I would like to store automatically, those images to an X folder on Google Drive (the drive of my personal email address), saved as date&time.jpeg.

I know that there's [this script](http://www.labnol.org/internet/send-gmail-to-google-drive/21236/) that does a great work at storing emails, but as far as I understood it stores the whole email as .pdf.

Maybe gmail has a feature that I'm missing, or maybe there's a way to do this..

Comment: Your use case is to store the files in gmail directly to your Drive(on particular folder). In your gmail, on the attachment you see Drive button. Click on that button,you get folders list and save it to your drive particular folder. Attachments are saved on Drive as same type as the original attachment type. Let me know if your use case is different.

Comment: @SGC yes, I would like to do that automatically, as soon as I get the email..

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Google Apps Script. Refer [this project](https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive/tree/v2)